# What is actually happening when I encode a string into bytes?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, encoding

So I am confused about what it actually means to encode a string into bytes.

I obviously understand that everything in a computer is represented by a sequence of 1's and 0's and eight of those together is one byte. So I am getting confused by the encoding operation on strings. For example, in Python, you write a string or you can write a bytes version of the string like so.

```
'foo' # usual string
b'foo' # bytes version of the string
```

How do these actually differ in memory if both still need to be represented by a sequence of 1's and 0's?